# Conversion of C# Code to LINQ C# but list adding same items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

programmers, I am trying to filter the list. I did with foreach loops and it's working fine but when I converted it to LINQ it's not working properly because the filtered list is adding the same items while I need different items picked from another list according to my condition.
I did the following code with loops and it's working fine and showing me the result.

```
  foreach (var item in lists)
        {
            if (item.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var newitem in item.Items)
                {
                    foreach (var assulkeylist in list)
                    {
                        if (newitem.Href.Contains(assulkeylist.ApplicationKey))
                        {
                            if (!filteredlist.Contains(newitem))
                            {
                                filteredlist.Add(newitem);
                            }
                           
                        }
                    }
                   
                }
            }
            
        }
```

[This is the result from using forloops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxGeB.png)

And here what I did with **LINQ C#**. but it's showing me **12 items** and all items have same name:

What code I did with LINQ given below don't know what's the problem where I am facing.

```
List<ListItem> filteredlist = new List<ListItem>();
            filteredlist = (from ListItem item in lists
                                           where item.Items.Count > 0
                                           from newitem in item.Items
                                           from assulkeylist in list
                                           where newitem.Href.Contains(assulkeylist.ApplicationKey)
                                           where !filteredlist.Contains(newitem)
                                           select newitem).ToList();
```

[Result from LINQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYkno.png)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: You can't do a `where !filteredlist.Contains(newitem)` inside the LINQ query. That makes no sense. Your list is empty.

Comment: Your LINQ query has a different types than the normal code. Can you please provide a [mcve] for the original `for`-style code?

Comment: `!filteredlist.Contains(newitem)` is not needed. `Distinct` _will_ be needed.

Comment: @mjwills - I think it's even better than that. The OP's doing an unnecessary cartesian product and that's ***generating duplicates***.

Comment: The way you use `list` in the LINQ query produces the *product* of all matching `item` and `assulkeylist` entries. Instead trying to convert the original loop keyword-for-keyword, try to understand what it does first. That `foreach (var assulkeylist` looks like a check to see if `newItem` matches any items in `list`, something that can be done with `list.Any(someCondition)`

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio try [Convert ForEach loop to LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-foreach-linq?view=vs-2017#convert-a-foreach-loop-to-linq-refactoring)

Comment: I did this but there was error of unassigned local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem myself by doing this:

```
List<ListItem> filteredlist = new List<ListItem>();
filteredlist = (from item in lists
                where item.Items.Count > 0
                from newitem in item.Items
                from assulkeylist in list
                where newitem.Href.Contains(assulkeylist.ApplicationKey)
                where !filteredlist.Contains(item)
                select item).ToList().Distinct().ToList();

List<ListItem> mymainlist = (from myitem in lists
                             where myitem.Items.Count == 0
                             select myitem).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
List<ListItem> filteredlist =
(
    from item in lists
    from newitem in item.Items
    where list.Any(l => newitem.Href.Contains(l.ApplicationKey))
    select newitem
).ToList();
```

You're only adding the first `newitem` when you get the first `newitem.Href.Contains(assulkeylist.ApplicationKey)` match, so the whole `foreach (var assulkeylist in list) ...` can be replaced by an `.Any(...)`.

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick as well

```
filteredlist.AddRange(lists.Where(item => item.Items.Count > 0)
 .SelectMany(item => item.Items)
 .Where(newitem => !filteredlist.Contains(newitem) && 
  list.Any(assulkeylist => newitem.Href.Contains(assulkeylist.ApplicationKey))));
```

Comment: `.Where(newitem => !filteredlist.Contains(newitem) ` <-- This will have terrible runtime complexity. Use a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: @Dai I merely translated his code to Linq lingo... I don't even know what object type `filteredlist` is

Comment: I resolved this by using Distinct and then convert it into List now showing me only those which matched.